# Gulp task not working as expected

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I have 2 tasks:

- **whitelabel** - I have a gulp task that copies a given whitelabel project into a folder
- **sass** - compile the sass project within that folder

My problem is that when I put them to run in sequence on my default task the css the files are copied but the sass task doesnt generated the css it is suposed to. But, if i run one task than the other the css file is generated.

What am I missing?

### Whitelabel Task

```
gulp.task('whitelabel', function() {
    var argv = yargs.argv;
    if (argv.whitelabel){
      gulp.src('./whitelabels/_template/**/*')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets'));
      return gulp.src('./whitelabels/'+ argv.whitelabel +'/**/*')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
    } else {
      return gulp.src('./whitelabels/_template/**/*')
      .pipe(del.sync(['./assets/']))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
    }
});
```

### SASS Task

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('assets/styles/style.scss')
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.sass({
      style: 'expanded'
    }))
    .on('error', $.notify.onError({
      title: 'SASS Failed',
      message: 'Error(s) occurred during compile!'
    }))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/styles'))
    .pipe(reload({
      stream: true
    }))
    .pipe($.notify({
      message: 'Styles task complete'
    }));
});
```

### Default Task

```
gulp.task('default', ['config', 'browser-sync', 'whitelabel', 'sass', 'minify-css'], function() {
  gulp.watch('whitelabels/_template/assets/styles/*.css', function(file) {
    if (file.type === "changed") {
      reload(file.path);
    }
  });
  gulp.watch(['*.html', 'app/**/*.html', 'views/*.html'], ['bs-reload']);
  gulp.watch(['whitelabels/_template/assets/js/*.js'], ['whitelabel','bs-reload']);
  gulp.watch(['app/*.js'], ['bs-reload']);
  gulp.watch('whitelabels/_template/assets/styles/**/*.scss', ['whitelabel', 'sass', 'minify-css']);
});
```

Comment: Are you assuming that or needing 'whitelabel' to finish before 'sass' task?  Because it may or may not, they are not run sequentially.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that. It is suposed to finish before all other tasks in the sequence. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original default task does not guarantee that the tasks are run in any specific order - in fact they run in parallel.

Many people use run-sequence https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence to run tasks in a specified order.

Or you could make the 'whitelabel' task a dependency of the sass task by

```
gulp.task('sass', ['whitelabel'], function() {
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!